# Click in a children in a custom xamarin forms layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, onclick

I have this class derived from a `Layout<view>` which is the WrapLayout example from [Creating a Custom Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom#invalidatelayout):

Tthe code is a little big, so I put it in this pastebin:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace CustomLayout.ViewModels
{
   // ...
   // [EDIT] puting the relevant code for put the images whit 
   /// a tap gesture in the layout 

   var images = GetImages();
   int i = 0;
   foreach (var photo in images.Photos)
   {
       var image = new Image
       {
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource(photo),
            WidthRequest = 50,
            HeightRequest = 75
        };
        var cartaoTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        cartaoTap.Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            cartaoClick(i);
        };
        image.GestureRecognizers.Add(cartaoTap);
        customLayout.Children.Add(image);
        i++;
    }
    // ...
    private void cartaoClick(int index){
        Navigation.PushAsync(new CartaoPage(cartao.GetImagem(index), cartao.GetNome(index), cartao.GetDescricao(index)));
    }
}
```

[pastebin Raw Code for the CustomLayout class](https://pastebin.com/raw/Rgau2M00)

"Cartao" is a class with attributes like Nome, Descricao and Imagem.
In the tap gesture event I pass the int "i" value to the CartaoClcik(int index) method when I added the image in the CustomLayout, in my mind, I can get the index passed to the call of this method when I added the image in the click of the mouse in one of the image showed, but, when I run and click in a image, the index parameter is alawys of the last image added

[EDIT:].

After an inhumane search job on the internet, I see that is possible to implement a class derived from `Image()` and then implement the GestureRecognizer command directly in this class, but I dont know how I can implement that and also I dont know how to pass the parameter needed for the page to show the image in full screen in the `CartaoPage(Image img, string nome, string descr) whose parameters have to be passed in when the user click in a image showed in they screen

someone can help me?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @RobertAndrzejuk, sorry, the bot did not let me publish the example because there is a lot of code, so I used pastebin, but all of code is in the link

Comment: add a TappedGestureRecognizer to each child

Comment: I make this directly in each image when I paste the images to the class, but the image click always show the same image, i.e. it assign the click and dont change in another click

Comment: Hi @Jason, good morning, now I see that if I create a class derived from `Image()` is possible which I can implement my `TapGestureRecognizer();` directly in this class is a good way, but I dont know how to implement this method im `MyImageClass: Image` class, you can give any ideas?

Comment: please post the relevant code related just to the image click

Comment: ok, I will edit the post

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I solved this question, to solve I created a class derived from `Image()` with a `public int ID {get; set;}` and then fill this attribute when I instantiate my image using my own class and then I pass this ID for my index.
I know that not is a elegant solution but is working here.

thanks for all